# Manually instantiating ngModelController in test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

We have standardized on creating all new directives as controllers that then get married to the template in the directive. This allows us to test the primary functionality without having to use angular-html2js, which we need to eliminate from our workflow.

However, we'd rather not have to rewrite functionality that allows us to have a model with a complex view that helps users edit it. So I want to create a ngModelController manually and then retrieve it in $onInit using $element.controller().

The problem I'm having is that ngModelController doesn't seem to be registered properly with the injector, so I can't quite work out the syntax for how to make one.

I've tried 
    ngModel = $controller('ngModelController', { $scope: $scope, $attrs: { 'ng-model': 'measure' } });

```
ngModel = $controller('ngModel', { $scope: $scope, $attrs: { 'ng-model': 'measure' } });
```

and
    ngModel = $controller('NGModelController', { $scope: $scope, $attrs: { 'ng-model': 'measure' } });

None of these work.

I assume ngModelController has been tested, so it must be possible to get hold of it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually [found the answer](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7720). In a nutshell:

```
$scope=$rootScope.$new();
$scope.dummy='foo;
$compile('<input ng-model="dummy" />')($scope).controller('ngModel');
```

Hope this helps someone.